# Ambiguous use of operator '>'

Tags: swift, closures

i tried this

```
simple2 = {s1, s2 in s1 > s2}
```

and

```
var simple2 = {$0 > $1}
```

but still showing me

> swift 3 closure Ambiguous use of 'operator >'

Comment: The types probably aren't clear enough. It doesn't know which overload to use. Try adding type annotations or whatever Swift uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure must explicitly declare the type of the `s1` and `s2` parameters and that type must implement `>` operator. The typical way to do that is to make the signature of that closure ensure that the two parameters are (a) the same type; and (b) conform to the `Comparable` protocol.

If you want `simple2` to take *any* `Comparable` type, rather than a closure, you could define a generic function:

```
func simple2<T: Comparable>(_ s1: T, _ s2: T) -> Bool {
    return s1 > s2
}
```

Then you could call it with any `Comparable` type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the types of `s1` and `s2` and `$0` and `$1`. Not even a human can infer what type you want these to be of, let alone the Swift compiler.

`>` can be applied to multiple types. Here are some of the examples:

- `Int` and `Int`
- `Double` and `Double`
- `CGFloat` and `CGFloat`

You can specify the types like this:

```
let simple2: (Int, Int) -> Bool = {$0 > $1}
```

Comment: @EkramulHoque How would it know? Not even I know if you mean to compare ints, strings, or anything else